# How to make NFS server start if a disk mountpoint export fails to mount?

Tags: linux, nfs, mount

Consider the following `/etc/exports`:

```
/verbatim 192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
/sandisk 192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
```

`/verbatim` and `/sandisk` are mountpoints of external hard drives defined in `/etc/fstab` as follows:

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/06b24834-a749-4d93-b0d5-a6da71eaf224 /verbatim ext4 defaults 0 1
/dev/disk/by-uuid/d7dbea69-0332-4d12-b905-b9a116e28422 /sandisk ext4 defaults 0 1
```

Now, if any of these hard drives fails to mount - for example when it's powered off or uplugged - NFS server fails to start. These are what I believe the relevant entries in journal:

```
Sep 23 09:45:26 lilo systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-06b24834\x2da749\x2d4d93\x2db0d5\x2da6da71eaf224.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-06b24834\x2da749\x2d4d93\x2db0d5\x2da6da71eaf224.device/start timed out.
Sep 23 09:45:26 lilo systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device SAMSUNG_HD204UI 1.
Sep 23 09:45:26 lilo systemd[1]: Dependency failed for File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/06b24834-a749-4d93-b0d5-a6da71eaf224.
Sep 23 09:45:26 lilo systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /verbatim.
Sep 23 09:45:26 lilo systemd[1]: Dependency failed for NFS server and services.
Sep 23 09:45:26 lilo systemd[1]: nfs-server.service: Job nfs-server.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Sep 23 09:45:26 lilo systemd[1]: verbatim.mount: Job verbatim.mount/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Sep 23 09:45:26 lilo systemd[1]: systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-06b24834\x2da749\x2d4d93\x2db0d5\x2da6da71eaf224.service: Job systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-06b24834\x2da749\x2d4d93\x2db0d5\x2da6da71eaf224.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Sep 23 09:45:26 lilo systemd[1]: dev-disk-by\x2duuid-06b24834\x2da749\x2d4d93\x2db0d5\x2da6da71eaf224.device: Job dev-disk-by\x2duuid-06b24834\x2da749\x2d4d93\x2db0d5\x2da6da71eaf224.device/start failed with result 'timeout'.
```

Is there any way I can configure NFS server to start and serve the other drives (sandisk) even if some drives can't be mounted (verbatim)?

Comment: `fstab` and `nfs` are nothing to do each other. If you add mount to `fstab` and your disk is not available when `fstab` inisiates OS simple doesn't boots up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `mountpoint` or `mp` in [`/etc/exports`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/exports) :

> **`mountpoint=path`**
> **`mp`**
> This option makes it possible to only export a directory if it has successfully been mounted. If no path is given (e.g. mountpoint or mp) then the export point must also be a mount point. If it isn't then the export point is not exported. This allows you to be sure that the directory underneath a mountpoint will never be exported by accident if, for example, the filesystem failed to mount due to a disc error.
>
> If a path is given (e.g. mountpoint=/path or mp=/path) then the nominated path must be a mountpoint for the exportpoint to be exported.

```
/verbatim 192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,mountpoint)
/sandisk 192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,mountpoint)
```

Also, consider using `auto,nofail` in `/etc/fstab` so that operating system boots if external disks are unplugged or powered off:

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/06b24834-a749-4d93-b0d5-a6da71eaf224 /verbatim ext4 auto,nofail 0 1
/dev/disk/by-uuid/d7dbea69-0332-4d12-b905-b9a116e28422 /sandisk ext4 auto,nofail 0 1
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm actually surprised that NFS fails to start when a disk is not mounted. In a good way though. Because an unmounted disk appears simply as an empty directory, and exporting an empty directory shouldn't be a problem for the NFS server. If NFS would start, and export that empty directory, you wouldn't be in a good place either.

Your NFS clients would complain that their files are missing, or maybe not and they would start filling up your root file system.

If your disk recovers and is mounted again, it will be mounted on top of and hide the files that were written to the root file-system. Also not a good thing.

---

You could remove your unreliable and removable file systems from `/etc/exports`.

That solves the problem of the NFS server not starting when they are not mounted.

Once the NFS server is running, you can use [`exportfs`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/exportfs) with the `-i` flag (to ignore `/etc/exports` and complaints about missing entries) to control it.

That allows you to start exporting `/verbatim` on the running server only when the removable disk is attached, powered on and properly mounted.

---

The approach to automating that is for example by creating a custom systemd service that will run (only) once the `/verbatim` file system is successfully mounted:

1. Find the systemd mount name of /verbatim with `systemctl list-units -t mount` ; for example `verbatim.mount`
2. Create a custom service that will run the `exportfs` command , for example by creating it as `/etc/systemd/system/export-verbatim.service`
   The code below is the concept, not tested.

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description=Export /verbatim once mounted
   Requires=verbatim.mount
   After=verbatim.mount

   [Service]
   Type=oneshot
   ExecStart=/path/to/exportfs -i -and more -options

   [Install]
   WantedBy=verbatim.mount
   ```
3. Enable that new service `systemctl enable export-verbatim` and `systemctl start export-verbatim`.